# Sparkling Water setup on clean ubuntu machine

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, h2o

I've been trying to set up Hadoop/Spark/Sparkling Water on a clean Ubuntu 14.04 machine on a private cloud on Amazon.  Doing everything as root.  I successfully apt-get java-6, scala 2.10.5, then wget and unpack hadoop 2.6, spark 1.2.1, and sparkling water 0.2.1-47.

I exported HADOOP_HOME and SPARK_HOME to the correct directories, and ran bin/sparkling-shell:

```
import org.apache.spark.h2o._
import org.apache.spark.examples.h2o._
val h2oContext = new H2OContext(sc).start()
```

There then follows a massive amount of starting task X / finishing task X output, followed by

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot execute H2O on all Spark executors:
  numH2OWorkers = -1"
  executorStatus = (0,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(1,false),(2,false),(1,false),(1,false),(1,false),(1,false),(1,false),(1,false),(1,false),(1,false),(0,false),(1,false),(0,false),(1,false),(1,false),(0,false),(1,false),(0,false),(1,false),(1,false),(0,false),(0,false),(1,false),(1,false),(0,false),(0,false),(2,false),(2,false),(1,false),(0,false),(1,false),(0,false),(2,false),(1,false),(2,false),(1,false),(0,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(1,false),(2,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(2,false),(1,false),(0,false),(1,false),(0,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(2,false),(1,false),(1,false),(0,false),(2,false),(0,false),(2,false),(1,false),(1,false),(0,false),(1,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(2,false),(1,false),(1,false),(0,false),(2,false),(0,false),(2,false),(1,false),(1,false),(0,false),(2,false),(0,false),(2,false),(1,false),(0,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(1,false),(2,false),(1,false),(0,false),(2,false),(0,false),(2,false),(1,false),(2,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(1,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(2,false),(0,false),(1,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(2,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(1,false),(0,false),(2,false),(0,false),(1,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(2,false),(0,false),(1,false),(2,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(0,false),(1,false),(2,false),(2,false),(1,false),(1,false),(0,false),(0,false),(2,false),(2,false),(1,false),(0,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(2,false),(1,false),(0,false),(2,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(1,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(2,false),(2,false),(1,false),(1,false),(0,false),(2,false),(0,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(1,false),(2,false),(2,false),(1,false),(0,false),(0,false),(2,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(0,false),(1,false),(2,false),(1,false),(2,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(1,false),(0,false),(2,false),(1,false),(0,false),(1,false),(2,false),(0,false),(2,false),(0,false),(1,false),(0,false),(1,false),(2,false),(1,false),(2,false)
at org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OContext.start(H2OContext.scala:112)
(...)
```

Could somebody indicate what I might be doing wrong and/or missing?  If needed/helpful I can post my precise setup script.

Comment: Did you come across this error? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31236639/h2o-sparkling-water-error-while-creating-h2o-cloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this by building the project rather than downloading a zip.  The setup that currently works for me (I do not claim it is the only one that works) is: openjdk7, hadoop 2.6, spark 1.2.0.  Note HADOOP_HOME and SPARK_HOME must be exported shell variables, and the machine's private IP must be added to the /etc/hosts table, which can be done with:

```
echo $(ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d' ' -f1) $(hostname) localhost >> /etc/hosts
```

Then git clone the sparkling-water project and ./gradlew build in the project directory.