# H2O Sparkling Water Error while creating H2O cloud

Tags: scala, apache-spark, h2o

I have setup H2O Sparkling water and now following the instructions at http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/sparkling-water/rel-1.3/6/index.html - where step 3 says

```
import org.apache.spark.h2o._
val h2oContext = new H2OContext(sc).start()
```

I get following error after entering the last line. The error is as follows -

```
    scala> val h2oContext = new H2OContext(sc).start()
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/execution/LogicalRDD
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:20)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:22)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:26)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:28)
    at <init>(<console>:30)
    at .<init>(<console>:34)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:789)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1062)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:615)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:646)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:610)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:859)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:616)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:624)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loop(SparkILoop.scala:629)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:954)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LogicalRDD
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLC

lassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 42 more
```

As H2O Sparkling water is new release, there is not much help I could found on the web. If any one has come across such error or have any idea what could be possibly wrong, please help me to figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Spark 1.3 for Sparkling Water 1.3.6 release.

Naming of Sparkling Water releases follows Spark release:

- 1.2.x is for Spark 1.2
- 1.3.x is for Spark 1.3
- 1.4.x is for Spark 1.4

Comment: Yes, I figured it out later. Thanks tho!